# C# UWP accress to file, created by app, is denied

Tags: file, uwp

I am creating a C# UWP App, which creates files with broadFileSystemAccess capability.
Creating and writing to the file is no problem, but reading it fails with error message "Access to the path  is denied even when I use storageFile.Path after writing it (so path is guaranteed to be correct and I can open the file in a text editor without problem).

Can anyone tell me, what I may can do to fix the problem?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: The app is using broadFileSystemAccess and runFullTrust capabilities. When both are set in appxmanifest then the app is not listed in system settings for memory permission, but when I remove runFullTrust  capability it is. Writing seems to be no problem, but reading fails. Is there a way to use both permissions?

Comment: Even when I remove runFullTrust capability and enable access on file system in windows settings, reading the file fails with the error message above :(

Comment: The access to the path is even denied if I use the FileOpenPicker to open it!

Comment: Hello, can you provide some code to show the work you are currently trying? In addition, from your description, this may be related to the file you accessed. Is it a hidden file? Or the path is in a protected folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use following code to create a StorageFile, which can be read by my UWP app:

```
public static async Task<StorageFile> CreateStorageFileFromPath(string filepath)
{
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
    var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
    return await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
}
```

Kind regards,
Wolfgang